# Undefined method `column' for Foreigner::ConnectionAdapters::ForeignKeyDefinition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following when I try to run a migration:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `column' for #<Foreigner::ConnectionAdapters::ForeignKeyDefinition:0x007fa020938740>
```

Here's the migration code:

```
class CreateAdvertisement < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :advertisement do |t|
      t.integer :issue_id, null: false
      t.string :client_name, null: false
      t.decimal :size, null: false
      t.decimal :price, null: false
      t.decimal :commission_amount, null: false
      t.string :first_payment, null: false
      t.string :second_payment, null: false

      t.timestamps null: false
      t.foreign_key :issue
    end
  end
end
```

I have Foreigner 1.6.1 installed, Rails 4.2.0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 24):

You, or one of your gems use the 'foreigner' gem, which is deprecated with rails 4.2.0

You should update it or remove this dependency.
Maybe someone already did it, for example i use 'mailboxer' gem, and 'github.com/div' already forked the project to create a branch, so i changed my Gemfile :

```
gem 'mailboxer', :git => 'git://github.com/div/mailboxer.git', :branch => 'rails42-foreigner'
```

Comment: See also the Github discussion around this issue, which contains other approaches too: https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/issues/316

Answer (score 19):

You don't need foreigner with Rails 4.2, as it already has foreign-key support built-in. The syntax is very similar (although not identical) to foreigner.

See: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#foreign-key-support

Comment: This should be the correct answer since Rails 4.2 supports foreign key definition syntax.

Comment: use option on_delete: :cascade instead of dependent: :delete

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Simply removing 'foreigner' from the Gemfile fixes the issue.